# StreetSmash "???" Token

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

When playing StreetSmash, I recently encountered someone who should have the Shulk token. When I met them, the token said "???" on the token name, and the token image was a giant "?".

In the token select, there is no "???" or "Random" caracter.

btw they have the greeting

> I will hack you

I have actually not asked them if they know real hacking, so I think "???" May just be his hacking.

But, I also think it's a waste of time to hack like this, so I think it may be an error with not connect in time, like when the communication get's inturupted.

I can't think of any other reasons of why this glitch/hack occurred.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot somehow? (You'll need a New 3DS to do so I guess.)

Comment: Is it possible that it's a character you haven't unlocked?

Comment: That's what I thought too, but the question claims he knows the token's supposed to be Shulk, who is a starter. So unless the other guy surreptitiously changed it to Mewtwo or something that's not it.

Comment: @Seiyria I have evreything unlocked, so this could not be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked them the other day, and they are useing Mewtwo. I do not have Mewtwo.